# I would like to know where the location of the Java 9 src.zip is located

Tags: java, java-9

Does anyone know where the src.zip is for Java 9. For versions 7 & 8 it was in the linux tar and not in the windows zip, but I've gone through all the linux tars and it's not there.

Comment: The src.zip file is located under the lib directory of the JDK on both my Windows and Linux machines.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. You **might** try your luck at [softwarereqs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) - but **first** study the corresponding help center to enable yourself to understand the policies of that community (instead of again dumping a question that violates the terms and conditions of that community). And consider deleting *this* question please! Thanks!

Comment: Typing `src.zip` into the search box of your preferred file manager takes far less than writing this question on Stackoverflow. Besides that, it has always been included in the Windows JDK as well.

Answer (score 12):

As noted in one of the comments, src.zip is now in the lib directory. More on this in the [JDK 9 Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html#JDK-8049367) and [JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220).

> ***src.zip*** has moved from the top-level directory to the ***lib*** directory
>   and now includes both the JDK and JavaFX source files in module
>   directories. IDEs or tools that open this zip file may need to be
>   updated.